# flutter_stripe package doesn't work in flutter web

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-stripe

I have implemented the flutter_stripe package with flutter and it works fine in mobile but when tested on web I always get this error :

`You may test your Stripe.js integration over HTTP. However, live Stripe.js integrations must use HTTPS.`

Also I have the flutter_stripe_web package added to pubspec.yaml, My website already has https and the payment node.js code is hosted on firebase functions, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: is your frontend hosted on https as well, not just your node.js code? Could you provide some code or even better a way to access your website and see what's happening there?

Comment: My website is hosted on netlify, here's the link: [bookdoor](https://bookdoor.net) ... I honestly don't know if my front end has https or not, is there a way to know?

Comment: where's the page that has the Stripe.js code?